# Empty sprint burndown chart

Tags: azure-devops, devops, burndowncharts

I'm trying to setup azure devops test project and introduce it to our team. So I created test user stories and related tasks. I also created test sprints (10 work days each) starting with 2021-07-19. So far so good. Taskboard contains tasks and user stories, for test purposed I "finished" some work yesterday. Backlog tab seems to be working well, remaining work and work details works as expected too. Capacity tab is filled.

But once I enter Analytics tab with burndown trend it seems to be empty. No task nor user stories. Did I miss something? I tried all tutorials and all seems to be set correctly. See pictures below.

[image: Taskboard tab]

[image: Backlog tab]

[image: Capacity tab]

[image: Analytics tab]

Do you have any advice or hints?

Thanks!

EDIT: Legacy burndown graph in dashboard works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I found solution. My test project contains only user stories and related tasks and thus the structure is obviously *User story -> Tasks*. However in the *project setting -> Boards - Team configuration* I left checked also Features checkbox. Based on that setting expected structure is *Feature -> User stories -> Tasks* which I haven't. So once I unchecked Features checkbox all started to work as expected. I might be useful for others as well.